# Relationship between the number of runs in tensorboard and the configuration of google cloud machine learning job

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard

When I use tensorboard to show the data, I found that there is more than one curve. I think this is related to the configuration. So could someone tell me what each curve represents?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not related in any way with the Cloud ML Engine. You can find 
all the configurable parameters for the Engine in the docs for its REST API  ([training input](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#traininginput), [training output](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#trainingoutput), [prediction input](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#predictioninput), [prediction output](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#predictionoutput), [model resource](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models#resource-model), [version resource](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models.versions#resource-version)).
These curves from your tensorboard is something you configured in your tensorflow code, probably the training cost for several different runs, set as a summary scalar with the name "train_cost".